# On the invariance of ball $B(a,r)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, contraction-operator

Let $X$ be a complete metric space and a continuous map $ f: X \to X $. A condition sufficient for a ball $ B(a, r) \subseteq X  $ to be invariant by $ f $, that is $ f \left (B (a, r) \right) \subseteq B (a, r) $, is that:

- $ f|_{B(a,r)} $ is a $\lambda$-contraction,
- $ d(f (a), a) <r (1-\lambda)$.

Are there other criteria over $f$ for  invariance of ball $ B (a, r) $? That is, not based on these two conditions over $f$ ? Any references?